# Eclipse Neon Tomcat plugin download error

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, eclipse-neon

I am trying to download tomcat plugin in Eclipse Neon. Some how I managed to download it. But when I try to set preferences for tomcat using *Windows-> Preferences -> Tomcat*. It is giving me below error. I think some plugin activator is missing in Eclipse. if you can take a look at it.

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.uqbar.eclipse.tomcat.xt (706).
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.hooks.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:116)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:529)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.findLocalClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:325)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:345)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:423)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:372)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:364)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:161)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.loadClass(EquinoxBundle.java:564)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:174)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:905)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:243)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:55)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin$1.run(WorkbenchPlugin.java:291)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin.createExtension(WorkbenchPlugin.java:286)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.WorkbenchPreferenceNode.createPage(WorkbenchPreferenceNode.java:48)
at org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferenceDialog.createPage(PreferenceDialog.java:1280)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.FilteredPreferenceDialog.createPage(FilteredPreferenceDialog.java:355)
at org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferenceDialog.showPage(PreferenceDialog.java:1167)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.FilteredPreferenceDialog.showPage(FilteredPreferenceDialog.java:608)
at org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferenceDialog$5.lambda$0(PreferenceDialog.java:656)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
at org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferenceDialog$5.selectionChanged(PreferenceDialog.java:653)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$3.run(StructuredViewer.java:878)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:173)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.firePostSelectionChanged(StructuredViewer.java:875)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.handlePostSelect(StructuredViewer.java:1244)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$5.widgetSelected(StructuredViewer.java:1270)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.firePostSelectionEvent(OpenStrategy.java:265)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.access$5(OpenStrategy.java:259)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy$1.lambda$1(OpenStrategy.java:431)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:182)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4203)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3819)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:818)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:794)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.WorkbenchPreferenceDialog.open(WorkbenchPreferenceDialog.java:211)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.OpenPreferencesAction.run(OpenPreferencesAction.java:63)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent(Action.java:473)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:565)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.lambda$4(ActionContributionItem.java:397)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4410)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1079)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4228)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3816)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$4.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1121)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1022)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:150)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:687)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:604)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:148)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:138)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:673)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:610)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1519)
```

Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Error loading bundle activator.
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:716)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.startWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:932)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.startWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:581)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:449)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:470)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.hooks.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:107)
    ... 71 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.core.internal.compatibility.PluginActivator cannot be found by org.uqbar.eclipse.tomcat.xt_2.0.0
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:461)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:372)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:364)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.loadBundleActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:757)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
    ... 77 more

Comment: It seems aspectjtools-1.5.4.jar is missing in your classpath. Refer https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.aspectj/aspectjtools/1.5.4

Comment: aspectjtools-1.6.11.jar is already there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By trying to download it from eclipse market place did not help me. I downloaded the plugin manually from [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/tomcatplugin/?source=navbar) and installed in eclipse. and it worked for me.

Thanks